# How can I check if a field exists in a specific document in Firebase Firestore / Swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if a field exists in a specific document in firebase firestore or not.
I already have the location of the document, but I can't find anything in the Firebase documentation in Swift.
Anyone can help me?
Maybe with a snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I managed to do, is there a best way to do it? (when you retrieve a doc you get it under the form ["field": value]

```
  let clientDocRef = db.collection("co1").document("doc1")
            clientDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                    print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                    if dataDescription.contains("\"Field1\"") {
                        print ("field exists")
                    } else {
                            print("field doesnt exist") }
                    } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            }
```